# How to add second button for media player in to a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I need a bit of help for adding a second button in my list view to stop Media Player from playing . It's a normal List View with a XML that define the items in the list (one text and one button). Or where to add the method  to stop playing on second click . Now the code is working, Media Player starts when the button is clicked and it stopped when a different button in the list is clicked, but i want to stop it when i click the button second time.I need a hint because i m going crazy.... Thank you.
My code :

```
 public class Songs extends Activity implements      Songs Custom Adapter . Play Sound Alert  {


ListView lstSounds;
SongsCustomAdapter soundsAdapter;
SongsCustomAdapter2[] mySounds;


MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.songs_listview);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);

    lstSounds = (ListView)

            findViewById(R.id.soundList);


    mySounds = new SongsCustomAdapter2[10];
    SongsCustomAdapter2 s1 = new SongsCustomAdapter2();

    SongsCustomAdapter2 s10 = new SongsCustomAdapter2();

    // Set sound one to a beep
    s1.setSoundName("1");
    s1.setSoundUri(R.raw.a1);

    s10.setSoundName("1");

    s10.setSoundUri(R.raw.a10);

    // Add sounds to the list
    mySounds[0] = s1;

    mySounds[9] = s10;

    soundsAdapter = new

            SongsCustomAdapter(this, mySounds);

    lstSounds.setAdapter(soundsAdapter);


}

@Override
public void playSound(int uri) {
    // Play sound
    stopPlaying();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
    if (!mp.isPlaying())

        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

    }


private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}


 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {

   stopPlaying();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}




@Override
public void onStop() {

    super.onStop();


}
```

Adapter

```
public class SongsCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    SongsCustomAdapter2[] sounds;
    Activity context;
    PlaySoundAlert soundPlayerAlert;


public SongsCustomAdapter(Activity context, SongsCustomAdapter2[] soundsArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sounds = soundsArray;


    this.soundPlayerAlert = (PlaySoundAlert)context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sounds == null ? 0 : sounds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return sounds[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    SongsCustomAdapter2 item = (SongsCustomAdapter2)getItem(i);

    if (view == null) // reuse existing view
        view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_songs,
                viewGroup, false);


    TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
    t.setText(item.getSoundName());


    ImageButton stopsong = (ImageButton)       view.findViewById(R.id.stop_song_list_btn);
    stopsong.setTag(item.getSoundUri());

    stopsong.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

public interface PlaySoundAlert {
    public void playSound(int uri);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ImageButton playsong = (ImageButton) view;


    if (playsong != null) {
        int soundUri = (int)playsong.getTag();

        if (soundPlayerAlert != null) {
            soundPlayerAlert.playSound(soundUri);
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Adapter2

```
public class SongsCustomAdapter2 {

    private int soundUri;
    private String soundName;

    public String getSoundName() {
        return soundName;
    }

    public void setSoundName(String soundName) {
        this.soundName = soundName;
    }

    public int getSoundUri() {
        return soundUri;
    }

    public void setSoundUri(int soundUri) {
        this.soundUri = soundUri;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Songs extends Activity implements      Songs Custom Adapter . Play Sound Alert` does this compile?

Comment: public class Songs extends Activity implements SongsCustomAdapter.PlaySoundAlert, yes ....it's working ok now only with one button

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have any updates to make. You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link under the post. Thank you, Daniel.